# What effect does the Earth's rotation have on plate tectonics?

Tags: earth

I've been reading up on plate tectonics and found that there are several different driving forces involved. One of the main categories of driving force mentioned on Wikipedia is forces related to the Earth's rotation. The section on driving forces related to Earth rotation presents the information as a sort of historical dialogue of the scientific process, which is somewhat helpful but has left me confused as to exactly what role the Earth's rotation *does* play in plate tectonics.

**So how does rotation affect the movement of plates?**

Comment: If this post seems unusual to you, you might want to visit [this page](http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/140/how-do-we-determine-what-geoscience-questions-are-in-scope?cb=1).

Comment: You can rephrase this to how would rotations affect other planets; of different size or temperament.

Comment: @RealzSlaw Please see the link in my comment above.

Comment: @RealzSlaw Note that we do not yet know of another planet with plate tectonics.

Comment: The answer would then be theoretical, even if we don't have empirical evidence.

Comment: @RealzSlaw It is not really constructive to draw theory from one data point (Earth).

Comment: IMHO, I think you can draw a theory from one data point. One data point is about statistical evidence, where you don't necessarily know or care about the underlying mechanism. But if learn enough about the mechanism of the entire system, it can be possible to argue what would happen if you changed the system, even with only one data point.

Comment: @RealzSlaw But that's the thing, we don't know enough about what other systems there might be with plate tectonics. There could be variables we haven't considered.